# On Marshmallow+ app is not creating folder to store images

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-fragments, picasso

This is my base code that checks if OS is `marshmallow`

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

    if(checkAndRequestPermissions()){
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

}

//For pre M devices
dispatchTakePictureIntent();
```

This is the method that create images. This creates directory, and images in Lollipop devices, but in lollipop+ OS it does not create the directory, and images.

I am using [file pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) defined for Nougat, and its working fine for lollipop devices, but not for lollipop+ devices.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

    File photoFile= null;
    String timestamp;
    timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String path= "/app_cam/selfie_"+timestamp+".jpg";

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        photoFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(path);

        String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";
        filePath = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, photoFile);



        takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, filePath);

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

I get following error message from `picasso`

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory at
>   android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method) at
>   android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:253)
>   at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:199)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.openFile(FileProvider.java:544)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1363)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) at
>   com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)

I asked for these permission from user;

- Manifest.permission.CAMERA
- Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

**EDIT**

As i have already set `filePath` in the `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` So `onActivityResult()` i do following.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(CameraLaucherActivity.this, PhotoEditor.class);
    intent.putExtra("filePath", filePath);
    startActivity(intent);
```

On the second activity, i get the `URI` from intent

```
Intent intentData = getIntent();
imageUri = (Uri) intentData.getExtras().get("filePath");
```

After that i do following to display `image` in `imageview`

```
Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri).config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).into(mImageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You should use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` to obtain a directory. You are using it for a file.

Comment: Further i wonder why picasso gets involved. Very strange.

Comment: @greenapps : I am using picasso to display image, I pass `filePath` to picasso, and also this is working fine on lollipop devices.

Comment: You showed the wrong code. There is nothing that takes a filepath and invokes Picasso. You post is very confusing. And further you are supposed to react on what i said about abusing a function.

Comment: @greenapps : sorry for the confusion, I have edited my question, please check now

Comment: You are still not reacting about that abuse.